# What is wrong with my MYSQL Workbench Query? (Error Code: 1064)

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am getting an error code (1064) when I attempt to run a query in MYSQL Workbench.  I have researched the error code and I'm aware that it is often thrown when a reserved keyword is used, a command is misspelled, or when using a depreciated command.  I have checked my code and I don't see any of the aforementioned errors.  I have made sure that the strings are all surrounded with quotation marks, the values and properties are in their corresponding positions, and that my sequelize model and datatypes are formatted appropriately.  However, when I try to run the query, I get a red squiggly line under one entry (saying that the entry is not valid in it's position and that a ')' is expected) and the error code.

```
INSERT INTO drycleaningprices(sameDayService, delivery, pickUpFee, dryCleaningPrices1-14, addInfo, sameDayInfo, deliveryHours, pickUpHours, EstablishmentBusinessName) 
VALUES (true, true,"$20.00",‍"kill","kill","kill","kill","kill","kill",‍"kill", "kill","kill",‍"kill","kill","kill",‍"kill","kill","kill","kill","kill","kill","Affordable Laundry")
```

I have even replaced each of the entries with duplicate strings to no avail.  In the above code, "dryCleaningPrices1-14" is actually 14 separate entries but was shortened for readability. And here is my model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){
    var DryCleaningPrices = sequelize.define("DryCleaningPrices",{
        sameDayService:{
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            defaultValue: false
        }, 
        delivery:{
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            defaultValue: false
        },
        pickUpFee:{
            type:DataTypes.STRING,
            defaultValue: "Enter Info"
        },
        freePickUp:{
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            defaultValue: false
        },
        deliveryOrderMinimum:{
            type:DataTypes.STRING
        },
        dryCleaningPrices1-14:{
            type:DataTypes.STRING
        },
        addInfo:{
            type:DataTypes.TEXT 
        },
        addInfo2:{
            type:DataTypes.TEXT 
        },
        addInfo3:{
            type:DataTypes.TEXT 
        },
        sameDayInfo:{
            type:DataTypes.TEXT 
        },
        deliveryHours:{
            type:DataTypes.STRING 
        },
        pickUpHours:{
            type:DataTypes.STRING 
        },
        createdAt:{
            type:DataTypes.DATE
        }, 
        updatedAt:{
            type:DataTypes.DATE
        } 
    })
    DryCleaningPrices.associate=function(models){
        DryCleaningPrices.belongsTo(models.Establishment,{
            foreignKey: {
                allowNull: false
            } 
        })
    }
    return DryCleaningPrices;
}
```

DDL:

```
Table   Create Table
    drycleaningprices   CREATE TABLE `drycleaningprices` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `sameDayService` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
   `delivery` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
   `pickUpFee` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Enter Info',
   `freePickUp` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
   `deliveryOrderMinimum` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `dryCleaningPrices1-14` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `addInfo` text,
   `addInfo2` text,
   `addInfo3` text,
   `sameDayInfo` text,
   `deliveryHours` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `pickUpHours` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `createdAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `updatedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `EstablishmentBusinessName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `EstablishmentBusinessName` (`EstablishmentBusinessName`),
   CONSTRAINT `drycleaningprices_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`EstablishmentBusinessName`) REFERENCES `establishments` (`businessName`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: Can please provide error description. I am expecting you have received something like this. ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id=101 SET name='foo'' at line 1

Comment: If you can paste the create table statement that also will be helpful to understand the problem

Comment: Yes.  It's a 1064.  You have an error in your SQL syntax.  And, I'm using sequelize, so the table creation is done behind the scenes using the Model provided above.

Comment: Can you run SHOW CREATE TABLE drycleaningprices; and get the DDL?

Comment: Yes, sir.  I've posted it above.

Answer (score 0):

Your Insert statement is incorrect you have given 9 column names but in Values you have given more than 9. Ideally your insert statement should look like this

```
INSERT INTO test.drycleaningprices
(sameDayService, delivery, pickUpFee,   `dryCleaningPrices1-14`, addInfo,  sameDayInfo, deliveryHours, pickUpHours,   EstablishmentBusinessName)
VALUES(true, true, "$20.00", "kill", "kill",  "kill", "kill","kill", '');
```

Please refer

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp